# How to plot a pie chart without overlapping labels on each other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a problem plotting a pie chart. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

count_legalgroups = Counter(data['LegalFormGroup']).most_common()

for_dict = dict(count_legalgroups)

    
legal_from_list = list(for_dict.keys())

count_from_list = list(for_dict.values())


slices = np.array(count_from_list)

activities = np.array(legal_from_list)

colors = ['yellowgreen','red','gold','lightskyblue','lightcoral','blue','pink', 
'darkgreen','grey','violet','magenta','cyan', 'brown']

patches, texts = plt.pie(slices,
   colors=colors,
   startangle=90,
   labels=activities)

labels = ['{0} - {1:1.2f} %'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(activities,
100.*slices/slices.sum())]
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.35, .5), fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

And I get this image:

[image: Plotted image I get]

I want it to be like this one:

[image: Desired image]

Any tips to fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: please add your data then we can run your code and debug

Comment: sorry, i can't show the data